# Re-direct image requests in RouteConfig file (ASP.NET MVC)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, chessboard.js

I'm having a problem using [**a jQuery plugin**](http://chessboardjs.com/) in an ASP.NET MVC Project, where images are being searched for in locations that don't exist.

I am receiving missing image errors like such:

```
GET http://localhost:51710/Home/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/bN.png 404 (Not Found)
```

But I have no idea why it seems to be searching for images inside of `localhost/Home` like that?

I want to search inside a content folder for the images of course, (e.g. `\Content\chessboard.js\img`), not a view/view controller like `localhost/Home`.

Why is this, and how can I achieve what I want?

My `routeconfig` file is still in it's default state:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

Here's the line in chessboard.js, where I can change the route **after** `localhost/Home`, but not `localhost/Home` itself:

```
cfg.pieceTheme = 'img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png';
```

Comment: Can you paste an example of the view code were you get the images?

Comment: @bejger It's not done in a view, it's done in chessboard.js (which is a very long file). I am able to change what's after localhost/Home in that file, so the problem must be in the routeconfig above surely?

Comment: Not neccessarily. Could you then paste a place from your chessboard.js file where you get images?

Comment: @bejger The above line is what I can change to change everything after `localhost/Home`, but not that part itself.

Comment: No code - voting to close. If you don't want to post code that causes problem (clearly there is some JavaScript code that grabs first part of the Url and concatenates to the second half) how do you expect people to help in your particular case? You indeed got useful advices to use built in server side functions to build Urls - but it is not going to help you with *your* code (may solve problem, which is all good than).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Here is the code - http://pastebin.com/YVVxi5XZ - there's honestly too much for me to handle in that, I can't find the bit which appends the second part (cfg.pieceTheme) onto the first (localhost/Home) :(

Comment: Looks like you get a solution with absolute url. Using absolute url makes sense because according to documentation [pieceTheme](http://chessboardjs.com/docs) it is source of an image and indeed relative url will be combined by browser with Url of current page so "/home/index" + "img/foo/bar.jpg" = "/home/img/foo/bar.jpg". If you home page would not contain "/" or second part at the end code would work ok: "/home" + "img/foo/bar.jpg" = /img/foo/bar.jpg".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use absolute path:

```
cfg.pieceTheme = '/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png'; // note the '/'
```

Comment: While it may work in general not a good idea - will break if one deploys application somewhere else and not at the root of site.

Comment: Yes, but usually websites are deployed right at the root folder. I haven't seen websites during last 5-10 years deployed at subfolders, because it breaks security.

Comment: +1. Ignore my previous comment (it should be about the way of building the string, not the fact that url must be absolute in this case). The property indeed must be set to absolute url (either hard-coded or constructed the way bejger suggested) because relative url will be combined with current page's url and result in unexpected url to the image.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very helpful Url extension to point to appropriate location of your content files (like images):

```
@Url.Content
```

Which makes it possible to get your files from appropriate content directories.

```
@Url.Content("~/Content/chessboard.js/img")
```

In case there is no possibility to use Razor syntax inside this file you could try this:

```
cfg.pieceTheme = "~/Content/chessboard.js/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png';
```